# Login Failed For User Error while connected with MSSQL Database from Oracle SQL Developer - in MAC Catalina

Tags: sql-server, macos, sql-server-2012, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hi I am using MAC Catalina and installed all the dependencies to connect MSSQL using Oracle Sql Developer.
But When i am entering my credentials, it is showing me "Login Failed For User" . Please help.

Just to add that i have used Razor sql, and was able to connect easily with same window Authentication(so no problem in permission or access is there). Since it was paid and my free trial was ended. I am trying to do it using SQL Developer.

[image]

Comment: Is the login using a Windows Auth or SQL Auth? If the former, you are missing the domain

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck "Use Windows Authentication".  If you provide a Username and Password that's (almost always) SQL Authentication, not Windows Authentication.

Comment: Hi David Thanks for your response, but when i uncheck "Use Window Auth" It is giving me the same error.   Login failed for user p0p029i

Comment: Then check the SQL Server erorrlog for details about the login failure.  Clients don't get login failure details for obvious security reasons.